# how to read xml file into richtextbox?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, richtextbox

I have my text formatted in xml and I want a richTextBox to display it like a browser would do - without any markups.

I've tried creating new XDocument..., XmlRead, XmlReadMode but nothing seems to work.

let's say my text goes like this:

```
<heading>


    <line> line the first </line> 
       <line> line the second </line>

</heading>
```

I want my richtextbox to display it like:

```
line the firs line the second
```

I am usging System.Xml and System.Linq, what should I add/try?

Comment: *"what should I add/try?"* add to *what*? Please post LINQ-to-XML codes that you have so far, then we can suggest what to add or change. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, man, it's so simple:

```
var xml = XElement.Load("test.xml");
richTextBox.Text = xml.Value;
```

Have you tried anything?